# How to fetch attendees from the Windows live events API using oauth?

Tags: oauth, calendar, omniauth, windows-live

I am trying the fetch the Windows calendar's events using oauth API.
I get the event details, but attendees of the events are missing.

Can anybody know how this can be retrieved from the WL API ?

Comment: Did you find a way to fetch the attendees?

Comment: Attendees cannot be fetched, as opposed to the privacy permissions from windows live. This option is given only to the apps developed as a partner of Microsoft.